# Adding headers with AWS SES

Tags: node.js, email, amazon-web-services

I've written a small node AWS Lambda function that uses AWS SES to send emails.

I'm trying to include a tracking pixel, and I'd like to add a no-cache email header:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Type: image/png
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0
```

Is there a way to do this with the regular `ses.sendEmail()` function? Or do I need to use the `sendRawEmail()` function (which seems like a huge pain)?

If the latter, are there simple node libraries to support this?

Answer (score 0):

Tracking pixel is not attached image, it's just link to remote image.
 Looks like `<img src="http://example.com/pixel.png?params">`